# Как сохранить соотношение сторон (aspect ratio) div с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я хочу создать div, который может изменять свою ширину / высоту при изменении ширины окна.

Существуют ли какие-либо правила CSS3, позволяющие изменять высоту в соответствии с шириной при сохранении соотношения сторон?
Я знаю, что могу сделать это с помощью JavaScript, но я бы предпочел использовать только CSS.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/7394871) от участника  [@ackb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77821/jackb).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/7394871

Answer (score 1):

## `vw` units:

Вы можете использовать единицы `vw` как для ширины, так и для высоты элемента. Это позволяет сохранить соотношение сторон элемента в зависимости от ширины области просмотра.

> vw : 1/100th от ширины viewport(области просмотра). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

В качестве альтернативы вы также можете использовать `vh` для высоты `viewport` (окна просмотра) или даже
`vmin / vmax` для использования меньшего / большего размера окна просмотра (обсуждение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630140/fit-responsive-square-in-viewport-according-to-width-and-height/23631436#23631436)).

### Пример: 1:1 aspect ratio

```css
div {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Для других соотношений сторон вы можете использовать следующую таблицу, чтобы вычислить значение высоты в соответствии с шириной элемента:

```
 aspect ratio  |  умножить ширину на
-----------------------------------
     1:1      |         1
     1:3      |         3
     4:3      |        0.75
    16:9      |       0.5625
```

### Пример: квадратная сетка 4x4.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  width: 23vw;
  height: 23vw;
  margin: 0.5vw auto;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673392/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Вы можете добиться этого с помощью SVG.**

Это зависит от случая, но в некоторых это действительно полезно. В качестве примера - вы можете установить `background-image` без установки фиксированной высоты или использовать его для встраивания youtube `<iframe>` с соотношением сторон 16: 9, `position:absolute` и т. д.

Для соотношения 3: 2 установите `viewBox = "0 0 3 2"` и так далее.

Пример:

```css
div{
    background-color:red
}
svg{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden
}

.demo-1{width:35%}
.demo-2{width:20%}
```

```html
<div class="demo-1">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 2"></svg>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="demo-2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 3 2"></svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58759325/7394871) от участника  [@Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9280523/jakub-muda).</sub>