# Как сжать квадратный блок?

Tags: html, css

Есть квадратный блок 600x600px. Нужно его сжимать при уменьшении ширины окна браузера, чтобы одновременно уменьшалась ширина и высота квадрата. Нужно чтобы пи сжатии получился квадрат 200x200px.

Comment: А впрочем, этот вариант может быть получше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185710

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
body {
  min-height: 600px;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```