# Как сжать квадрат?

Tags: html, css

Есть квадратный блок 600x600px. Нужно его сжимать при уменьшении ширины окна браузера, чтобы одновременно уменьшалась ширина и высота квадрата.
Нужно чтобы пи сжатии получился квадрат 200x200px.

Как это реализовать с помощью единиц измерения `vw,vh,px` и функцией `calc()`? Что-то наподобие такого `(calc((100vw - 35px) / 733 * 492))`

Comment: погуглите на тему flex-верстки, дядя

Comment: Хотя не, этот вариант получше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185710

Comment: @AVRamones, увы дядя, это тут не поможет.

Comment: Предлагаю восстановить данный вопрос, потому что: 1. уверен, что дубликат создат этим же автором, но от лица "гостя". 2. "дубликат", а точнее ссылка от [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185710/), не содержит __подтверждённого__ решения на вопрос.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 проголосовал против. автор должен сам тут или там обосновать причину переоткрытия и/или чем не подошёл предложенный ответ

Answer (score 3):

Всё, что нужно для реализации, уже давно придумали:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.square {
  max-width: 600px; min-width: 200px; width:100vw;
  max-height: 600px; min-height: 200px; height:100vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #808;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Можно использовать `aspect-ratio` (но, нужно дождаться нормальной [поддержки](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio) браузерами):

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.square {
  max-width: 300px; min-width: 200px; width:100vw;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #808;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```