# Пропорциональное изменение размеров дочернего элемента (полностью адаптивный квадрат) при изменении размеров родительского элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, адаптивная-верстка

У нас имеется следующий `HTML`+`CSS` код:

```js
function parentH() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').value + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.height = height;
  document.querySelector('#children').style.height = height;
}

function parentW() {
  let width = document.querySelector('#parent_range_W').value + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.width = width;
  document.querySelector('#children').style.width = width;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Изменяем высоту (H) родителя: <input id="parent_range_H" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_h" oninput="parentH()"></p>
<p>Изменяем ширину (W) родителя: <input id="parent_range_W" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_w" oninput="parentW()"></p>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

Родительский элемент `<div id="parent">` имеет одинаковые размеры  ширина - `300px` и высота - `300px`, образуя квадрат. Дочерний элемент `<div id="children">`, имея размеры в процентном соотношении (ширина - `100%` и высота - `100%`) от размеров своего родительского элемента, полностью заполняя всё его пространство, также образует квадрат. При изменении размеров родительского элемента, дочерний элемент, автоматически уменьшая свои размеры, подстраивается под размеры своего родительского элемента, и нарушает тем самым свои пропорции - квадрата.

**Вопрос:** Как при изменении размеров родительского элемента, пропорционально изменять размеры дочернего элемента? Дочерний элемент - это должен быть полностью адаптивный квадрат, и при любых изменениях высоты или ширины родительского элемента, дочерний элемент - квадрат - должен всегда оставаться квадратом. Какие есть варианты решения этой задачи?

Comment: Жаль, что нет метки CSS...

Comment: А  width 20vw height 20vw не канает что ли?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Вопрос: Как при изменении размеров родительского элемента,
> пропорционально изменять размеры дочернего элемента? Дочерний элемент
> должен быть полностью адаптивный квадрат, и при любых изменениях высоты или ширины родительского элемента, дочерний элемент - квадрат -
> должен всегда оставаться квадратом. Какие есть варианты решения этой
> задачи?

**Короткий ответ:**

Наиболее простой путь - использовать SVG, он лучше всего подходит для решения данной задачи.

---

- Начнем с базового примера, где для  простоты понимания исключим влияние `viewBox` на масштабирование и позиционирование. Он будет равен `width`, `height` SVG.
  Поэтому масштаб в этом примере - `1:1`
  И квадрат будет заполнять все внутреннее пространство  SVG.

*Примечание:*
Красная рамка - это граница SVG
Зеленая рамка - это граница родительского контейнера (в дальнейших примерах)

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" stroke="black" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

Метод JS `getBBox()` вычисляет физические размеры `100х100px` рамки окружающей квадрат, то есть в нашем случае - это будут размеры самого квадрата

**1. Добавляем родительский контейнер `200х200px`**

Так как у SVG фиксированные размеры, то он не будет масштабироваться и займет в родительском контейнере `100х100px`

```css
.container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**2.Родительский контейнер .container{width:300px; height:150px;}**

```css
.container{
width:300px;
height:150px;
outline:1px solid green;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**3. container{width:150px; height:300px;}**

```css
.container{
width:150px;
height:300px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

Это были примеры с ***фиксированными размерами*** SVG, при которых квадрат занимал место в родительском контейнере равным его собственным размерам `100х100px`

### Динамическое масштабирование SVG в родительском контейнере

Для этого ширина и высота SVG указывается либо в процентах, либо не указываются `width`,`height`, что эквивалентно `100%`

`width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100"`

**#1%. .container{width:200px;height:200px;**

Родительский контейнер в два раза больше, но svg с процентными значениями заполняет его полностью. Сравните с примером 1. выше, где у SVG были фиксированные размеры

**Обратите внимание!**
Квадрат растянулся до размеров родительского контейнера, так как соотношение сторон у контейнера 1:1 и у квадрата 1:1. поэтому на экране он отрендерился `200х200px` по размеру родителя, но его физические размеры (как он был задан в SVG) остались прежние `100х100px`, это показывает `getBBox()`

```css
.container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**#2%. container{width:300px;height:100px;**

Ширина родительского контейнера в три раза больше высоты, но он не растянулся на всю ширину остался `100х100px` так как указан параметр `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"`, который заставляет квадрат сохранять свои пропорции и прижиматься к левому краю

```css
.container{
width:300px;
height:100px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**#2.1. preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet"**

Прижимаем квадрат к правому краю родительского контейнера - `xMax`

```css
.container{
width:300px;
height:100px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**#2.2. preserveAspectRatio="none"**

Этот атрибут говорит SVG, что не надо сохранять пропорции, а так как `width="100%"` у SVG, то он растягивается на всю ширину родителя

```css
.container{
width:300px;
height:100px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

**#3%. container{width:100px;height:300px;**

Высота родительского контейнера в три раза больше высоты SVG, поэтому svg квадрат располагается на самом верху.

```css
.container{
width:100px;
height:300px;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

## Выводы:

- Для адаптивности SVG указывайте `viewBox`.
- `width height` в шапке SVG указывайте в процентах или не указывайте никаких
  значений, что эквивалентно 100%
- Чтобы SVG полностью заполнил родительский контейнер сделайте
  одинаковым соотношение `width, height` родительского контейнера и
  `width, height` SVG  (пример в этом ответе - **#1%.**)
- Не применяйте `preserveAspectRatio="none"` это нарушает пропорции
  соотношения сторон

### Update

**#4. Размеры родительского контейнера заданы в  единицах относительно окна браузера**

- Сначала происходит масштабирование svg относительно родительского
  контейнера
- Затем родительский контейнер масштабируется вместе с SVG относительно
  окна браузера

```
.container{
width:60vw;
height:20vh;
```

Понятно, что **итоговые размеры** родителя будут зависеть от разрешения и выбранного гаджета. Но заметьте, что физический размер квадрата SVG остается без изменений `100x100px` см. вывод консоли.
*Зачем это нужно?*
Это, размеры в исходной (inital) системе координат SVG.
Далее мы можем, как угодно трансформировать SVG, выводить результаты на экран,  сжимать, растягивать, но исходная система координат останется без изменений.

```css
.container{
width:60vw;
height:20vh;
outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;">  
         
<rect id="R1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="silver" />
</svg>
</div>  
<script> 
console.log(R1.getBBox())
</script>
```

Связанные топики:

**CSS**

1. [Как заставить элемент div автоматически изменять размер с сохранением aspect ratio (соотношения сторон)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1253431/28748)
2. [Ответ @web-tiki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185711/28748)

**SVG**

[Ответ @Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185725/28748)

Answer (score 5):

Подобный вопрос довольно часто встречается на ruSO. Поэтому мне кажется, что будет не лишним добавить готовое и полностью рабочее решение, которое может оказаться в будущем для многих пользователей полезным.

Вот один из вариантов такого решения поставленной задачи, с помощью `JavaScript` кода и с использованием переменных в `CSS`:

```js
function parentH() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').value;
  let width = document.querySelector('#parent_range_W').value;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.height = height + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#children').style.setProperty('--size', `${Math.min(height,width)}px`);
}

function parentW() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').value;
  let width = document.querySelector('#parent_range_W').value;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.width = width + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#children').style.setProperty('--size', `${Math.min(height,width)}px`);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#children {
  width: var(--size, 100%);
  height: var(--size, 100%);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Изменяем высоту (H) родителя: <input id="parent_range_H" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_h" oninput="parentH()"></p>
<p>Изменяем ширину (W) родителя: <input id="parent_range_W" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_w" oninput="parentW()"></p>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

И этот же вариант, только с небольшими изменениями в `JavaScript` и `CSS` коде. В этом случае установлен уже другой способ позиционирования у дочернего элемента. У родительского элемента значение остается прежним - `position: relative` - положение элемента установлено относительно своего исходного места. А вот дочерний элемент меняет свое положение на абсолютное позиционирование - `position: absolute`, где отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента:

```js
function parentH() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').valueAsNumber;
  let width = document.querySelector('#parent_range_W').valueAsNumber;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.height = height + 'px';
  let style = document.querySelector('#children').style;
  height <= width && (style.height = style.width = height + 'px');
}

function parentW() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').valueAsNumber;
  let width = document.querySelector('#parent_range_W').valueAsNumber;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.width = width + 'px';
  let style = document.querySelector('#children').style;
  height >= width && (style.height = style.width = width + 'px');
}
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#children {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Изменяем высоту (H) родителя: <input id="parent_range_H" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_h" oninput="parentH()"></p>
<p>Изменяем ширину (W) родителя: <input id="parent_range_W" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_w" oninput="parentW()"></p>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Непонятно, зачем проминусованы нормальный ответ и вопрос. Видимо сегодня неудачный день или плохое настроение у людей

Answer (score 4):

Отдельным ответом добавлю ещё один вариант, в котором мы будем менять у родительского элемента только высоту `height`, а у дочернего элемента только ширину `width`. При этом у нас всё также дочерний элемент должен пропорционально изменять свои размеры и всегда оставаться полностью адаптивным квадратом.

```js
function parentH() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').value;
  let width = document.querySelector('#children_range_W').value;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.height = height + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#children').style.setProperty('--size', `${Math.min(height,width)}px`);
}

function childrenW() {
  let height = document.querySelector('#parent_range_H').value;
  let width = document.querySelector('#children_range_W').value;
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.height = height + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#parent').style.width = width + 'px';
  document.querySelector('#children').style.setProperty('--size', `${Math.min(height,width)}px`);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;
}

#children {
  width: var(--size, 100%);
  height: var(--size, 100%);
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Изменяем высоту (H) родителя: <input id="parent_range_H" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_h" oninput="parentH()"></p>

<p>Изменяем ширину (W) квадрата: <input id="children_range_W" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="children_w" oninput="childrenW()"></p>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Resize элемента может происходить из-за изменения размеров окна браузера, из-за вставки текста / загрузки картинки, вручную (css-resize: both) или скриптом - из любого места кода.

На JS не нашел простого решения, который капитально покроет все случаи жизни. Поэтому разбиваю ответ на несколько конкретных вариантов:

**1**: Есть ровно один элемент (например, главное окно мини-игры), его нужно сделать квадратным, и обновлять размеры только при resize окна браузера.

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

updateSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);

function updateSize(wid, hei) {
  var wid = window.innerWidth;  // box.parentNode.clientWidth;
  var hei = window.innerHeight; // box.parentNode.clientHeight;

  box.style.width = box.style.height = Math.min(wid, hei) + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #500;
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

**1.1**: То же самое с защитой от дурака (Если каждое обновление размеров влечет за собой тяжелые изменения, пусть картинка не обновляется, если начнут играться и быстро ресайзить браузер)

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

updateSize();

window.addEventListener("resize", function resize() {
  clearTimeout(resize.timeout);
  resize.timeout = setTimeout(updateSize, 300);
  // Таймер сбросится и запустится заново, если в течение
  // 300 миллисекунд после предыдущего resize, произошло еще одно событие
});

function updateSize(wid, hei) {  
  var wid = window.innerWidth;
  var hei = window.innerHeight;

  box.style.width = box.style.height = Math.min(wid, hei) + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #500;
}

.box {
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**2**: Если предстоит создавать большое количество таких зависимых блоков (плохо представляю, зачем), приятно было бы иметь функцию, которая запомнит, от кого и к кому нужно передать размеры, и в каких пропорциях. А при изменении размеров, лишь вызвать метод, обновляющий размеры зависимых элементов. Примерно так:

```
let size = new Size({ from: parent, applyTo: child, ratio: 16 / 9, scale: 0.5 });

...onresize = () => size.update();
```

Резиновые блоки, обновляются и от input-ов, и при resize окна:

```js
function Size(obj) {
  this.source = obj.from;
  this.target = obj.applyTo;

  this.ratio = obj.ratio || 1; // Какое отношение (wid/hgt) соблюдать для target
  this.scale = obj.scale || 1; // Полученные размеры target будут домножться на scale

  this.update();
}

Size.prototype.update = function() {
  var f = parseFloat, s = getComputedStyle(this.source);
  var wid = this.source.clientWidth - f(s.paddingLeft) - f(s.paddingRight);
  var hei = this.source.clientHeight - f(s.paddingTop) - f(s.paddingBottom);

  var target = this.target.style;

  magic: {
    // Если захочется вникнуть, для удобства выставить ratio = 2/1 или 1/2
    if (wid / hei < this.ratio) {
      target.width = wid * this.scale + "px"; // Занимает 100% ширину
      target.height = wid * (1 / this.ratio) * this.scale + "px";
      // Высота подстраивается под ширину.
    } else {
      target.width = hei * this.ratio * this.scale + "px";
      target.height = hei * this.scale + "px";
    }
  }
}

/*** Использование ***/
let storage = [];

let parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
let child = document.querySelectorAll(".child");

for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
  storage[i] = new Size({
    from: parent[i],
    applyTo: child[i],
    ratio: 4 / 3,
    scale: 0.25 * (i + 1)
  });
}

function updateAll() {
  storage.forEach(e => e.update());
}

/***/
window.addEventListener("resize", updateAll);

first("#resize-w").addEventListener("input", resize);
first("#resize-h").addEventListener("input", resize);

function resize() {
  let dir = this.dataset.dir;
  let size = this.value + (dir == "width" ? "vw" : "vh");
  
  parent.forEach(e => e.style[dir] = size);
  updateAll();
}

function first(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background: #500;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="5" max="20" value="20" step="0.1" id="resize-w" data-dir="width"/> W
<input type="range" min="5" max="80" value="80" step="0.1" id="resize-h" data-dir="height"/> H
<hr>
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

Блоки не обязательно должны быть родительскими, могут быть где угодно. К одному блоку можно привязать несколько других, в разных местах.

**2.1**: Применительно к коду из вопроса:

```js
// *Демонстрирует работоспособность. Бессмысленно воротить такое ради одного элемента.

function Size(obj) {
  this.source = obj.from;
  this.target = obj.applyTo;

  this.ratio = obj.ratio || 1; // Какое отношение (wid/hgt) соблюдать для target
  this.scale = obj.scale || 1; // Полученные размеры target будут домножться на scale

  this.update();
}

Size.prototype.update = function() {
  var f = parseFloat, s = getComputedStyle(this.source);

  var wid = this.source.clientWidth - f(s.paddingLeft) - f(s.paddingRight);
  var hei = this.source.clientHeight - f(s.paddingTop) - f(s.paddingBottom);
  
  var target = this.target.style;

  magic: {
    if (wid / hei < this.ratio) {
      target.width = wid * this.scale + "px";
      target.height = wid * (1 / this.ratio) * this.scale + "px";
    } else {
      target.width = hei * this.ratio * this.scale + "px";
      target.height = hei * this.scale + "px";
    }
  }
}

/*****/
let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
let child = document.querySelector("#children");

let size = new Size({ from: parent, applyTo: child, ratio: 1 });

function resize(range, direction) { // -> HTML, oninput
  parent.style[direction] = range.value + "px";
  size.update();
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#children {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Изменяем высоту (H) родителя: <input oninput="resize(this, 'height')" id="parent_range_H" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_h"></p>
<p>Изменяем ширину (W) родителя: <input oninput="resize(this, 'width')" id="parent_range_W" type="range" min="10" max="300" value="300" step="1" name="parent_w"></p>

<div id="parent">
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

---

**3**. Заранее не известно, откуда может происходить resize, но очень нужно контролировать размеры блока. [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

```js
var box = document.querySelector("#box");

var observer = new ResizeObserver(function(e) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e); // <-- вся необходимая информация о размерах,
                  // которую можно дальше как-то обрабатывать.
});

observer.observe(box);
/***/

box.style.width = "50vw"; // <-- сработает observer.
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" oninput="box.style.width = this.value + 'vw';">

<div id="box"></div>
```

[Поддерживается](https://caniuse.com/?search=ResizeObserver) во всех современных браузерах.

Если нужна поддержка старых, можно написать функцию, которая, например, раз в полсекунды (`setInterval(fn, 500)`) или 60 раз в секунду (`requestAnimationFrame`) проверяет размер нужного блока и в случае обнаружения изменений, выполняет функцию. Или гуглить → *resize observer polyfill*