# Как заставить элемент div автоматически изменять размер с сохранением aspect ratio (соотношения сторон)?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я пытаюсь разместить div по центру экрана.
Этот div должен иметь определенную ширину и высоту, когда он помещается в доступное пространство окна, но он должен сжиматься, чтобы соответствовать, когда доступного пространства окна недостаточно, а также с сохранением исходного соотношения сторон (aspect ratio).

Я просмотрел множество примеров, которые работают с уменьшением ширины, но ни один из них не работает с изменением ширины и высоты в размере окна.

Вот мой текущий CSS:

```
* {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.stage_wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: gray;
}
.stage {
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: chocolate;
    object-fit: contain; /* I know this is for images, it's an example of what I'm looking for */
}
```

И мой текущий HTML:

```
<div class="stage_wrapper">
    <div class="stage">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Здесь показан центрированный блок div с фиксированной шириной `960px` и фиксированной высотой `540px`
Это  должны быть  максимальные размеры.

Затем, если я изменю размер своего окна, чтобы иметь меньшую ширину или высоту, элемент div должен успешно сжиматься - за исключением того, что он не поддерживает `original aspect ratio`, и это то, что я ищу.  Я хочу, чтобы он реагировал на изменения как ширины, так и высоты.

Это вообще возможно?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to make div element auto-resize maintaining aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65864203/7394871) от участника  [@Francisco Zarabozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162673/francisco-zarabozo).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65864203/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вот идея использования `viewport unit` и `clamp()`. Это своего рода `if else`, чтобы проверить, больше или меньше ширина экрана, чем высота (с учетом соотношения), и на основе результата мы делаем расчет.

В приведенном ниже коде есть две переменные `cv` и `ch`, и только одна из них будет равна 1

- Если это `cv`, то ширина больше, поэтому мы устанавливаем высоту на
  `cv`, а ширина будет основываться на этой высоте, поэтому логически
  это равно `cv / ratio`
- Если это `ch`, то высота больше, поэтому мы устанавливаем ширину на
  `cv`, а высота будет основана на этой ширине, поэтому логически это
  равно `ch / ratio`

В `clamp()` я использую `1vh / 1vw`, которое я умножаю на `90`, что эквивалентно вашим `90%`, чтобы иметь `90vh / 90vw`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}


.stage {
  --r: calc(960 / 540);
  
  --cv: clamp(0px,(100vw - 100vh*var(--r))*10000,1vh);
  --ch: clamp(0px,(100vh*var(--r) - 100vw)*10000,1vw);

  height: calc((var(--cv) + var(--ch)/var(--r)) * 90 );
  width:  calc((var(--ch) + var(--cv)*var(--r)) * 90 );
  
  max-width: 960px;
  max-height: 540px; /* OR calc(960px/var(--r)) */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
  background: 
    /* this gradient is a proof that the ratio is maintained since the angle is fixed */
    linear-gradient(30deg,red 50%,transparent 50%),
    chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Теоретически зажим можно упростить до:

```
--cv: clamp(0px,(1vw - 1vh*var(--r)),1vh);
--ch: clamp(0px,(1vh*var(--r) - 1vw),1vw);
```

Но чтобы избежать каких-либо проблем с округлением и не попадать в такие значения, как `0.x`, я выбираю большое значение, чтобы оно всегда было ограничено до `1`, если оно положительное.

### UPDATE

Кажется, в Firefox есть ошибка, поэтому вот еще одна версия того же кода:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: gray;
}


.stage {
  --r: calc(960 / 540);
  
  --cv: clamp(0px,(100vw - 100vh*var(--r))*100,90vh);
  --ch: clamp(0px,(100vh*var(--r) - 100vw)*100,90vw);

  height: calc((var(--cv) + var(--ch)/var(--r)) );
  width:  calc((var(--ch) + var(--cv)*var(--r)) );
  
  max-width: 960px;
  max-height: 540px; /* OR calc(960px/var(--r)) */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
  background: 
    /* этот градиент является доказательством того, что соотношение сохраняется, поскольку угол фиксирован */
    linear-gradient(30deg,red 50%,transparent 50%),
    chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864592/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>